# "getView" - the constant change of position of Items and I have to click twice of "Item"

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a realization of `ArrayAdapter` (extends `ArrayAdapter`), the method getView constantly redraw the screen,constantly changing position item of the `ListView.` But this is not the only problem. When I want to make text changes - are **re-sorted**. As well as to activate the line by `setOnClickListener` I have to **click twice**

My source

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        UrlItem urlItem = (UrlItem) this.getItem(position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            viewHolder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {                   


                    int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
                }
            });



            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

            convertView.setTag(R.id.editText1, viewHolder.text);
            viewHolder.text.setTag(position);
            viewHolder.text.setText(urlItem.getUrl());
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;

    }
```

[image]

Helped me to [this link.](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything with your views when they are recycled (i.e. when convertView != null). You need to do any position-specific stuff after obtaining the viewHolder. Try something more along these lines:

```
if (convertView == null) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    viewHolder.text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {                   


            int getPosition = (Integer) v.getTag();
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.text.setTag(position);
viewHolder.text.setText(urlItem.getUrl());

return convertView;
```

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear that - I've used code that follows that pattern many times with no problems. I wonder if the problem lies somewhere else in your adapter class?

Comment: If only I knew what the problem is - I would have decided =) Try to add a text field in the ListView - understand the problem