# Using onClick() to Set Text Inside of getView() for BaseAdapter-extended Class

Tags: android, onclick, baseadapter

I'm using one of the classes provided by [openaphid](https://github.com/openaphid) to do a flip view. The problem I'm running into (as I'm just beginning to find out) is that as new views get created and old ones are scrapped (inside `getView()`), the references to my variables are renewed and, thus, have different IDs, which results in me not being able to change them.

Essentially, what I have are 2 `TextView`s. One of the `TextView`s (`txtvwCharacter`) has been set as clickable in the `XML` and what I'm trying to do is: when `txtvwCharacter` gets clicked/touched, the other `TextView` (`txtvwComposition`) gets toggled between `"some text"` and `""` (empty string).

Below is a simplified version of my code, as I'm only focusing on the getView() method:

```
public class TravelAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ArrayList<String> characterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> compositionArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    TextView txtvwCharacter, txtvwComposition;

    boolean detailsOn = false;

    public TravelAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View layout = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) 
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complex1, null);

        txtvwCharacter = UI.<TextView>findViewById(layout, R.id.txtvw_character);
        txtvwComposition = UI.<TextView>findViewById(layout, R.id.txtvw_composition);

        txtvwCharacter.setText(characterArray.get(position));
        txtvwComposition.setText("");

        txtvwCharacter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(detailsOn == false)
                {
                    txtvwComposition.setText(compositionArray.get(position));
                    detailsOn = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtvwComposition.setText("");
                    detailsOn = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return layout;
    }
}
```

At the moment, with this code, the `onClick` does get registered and the `txtvwComposition` does get set, but it's not the same `txtvwComposition` that's being displayed, so, visually, it looks like nothing's happening.

I'd like to have some sort of persistence here, where when I click on `txtvwCharacter`, it knows that it's that one `TextView` object, and not a new one that's been instantiated between all the flip back and forth. (Sorry, I don't know how to phrase that better.)

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953875/getview-the-constant-change-of-position-of-items-and-i-have-to-click-twice-o) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354410/how-to-controll-textview-by-button-onclick-in-getview-method), but I don't understand what `ViewHolder` does, how it knows what to "hold," or how to apply it to my specific code here.

**CODE EDIT:**

```
public class TravelAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    ArrayList<String> characterArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> compositionArray = new ArrayList<String>();

    TextView txtvwCharacter, txtvwComposition;

    boolean detailsOn = false;

    public TravelAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View layout = convertView;

        if (convertView == null) 
            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complex1, null);

        txtvwCharacter = UI.<TextView>findViewById(layout, R.id.txtvw_character);
        txtvwComposition = UI.<TextView>findViewById(layout, R.id.txtvw_composition);

        if (detailsOn == false)
        {
            txtvwCharacter.setText(characterArray.get(position));
            txtvwComposition.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            txtvwCharacter.setText(characterArray.get(position));
            txtvwComposition.setText(compositionArray.get(position));
        }

        txtvwCharacter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
                TextView txtvwComposition = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.txtvw_composition);

                if(detailsOn == false)
                {
                    txtvwComposition.setText(compositionArray.get(position));
                    detailsOn = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtvwComposition.setText("");
                    detailsOn = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return layout;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply navigate the view hierarchy in the `onClick` method using the `v` reference to get to that row's `txtvwComposition`.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but I don't have a problem getting the value for `txtvwComposition`, I have a problem setting its text value appropriately. Please elaborate if I'm mistaken.

Comment: For example, if your row layout is a LinearLayout containing the two `TextViews` you could simply do: `LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) v.getParent(); TextView txtvwComposition = root.findViewById(R.id.txtvw_composition);` in the `onClick()` method. Right now those variables will not reference the proper views because they will always point to the TextViews from one of the last rows(the last calls to getView()).

Comment: Your suggestion was an excellent one and I've altered my code. It did allow the `onClick` to toggle the `txtvwComposition` very predictably. I have, however, run into an unexpected problem after that. The problem is: as I'm toggling, the value for `detailsOn` does change correctly, but when I'm flipping (i.e., `getView()` gets called again), while the new `detailsOn` value does get registered correctly, nothing happens in the `if` and `else` clauses (`txtvwComposition` doesn't get set properly). It doesn't seem like I can solve it with the same strategy as what's inside the `onClick()` clause.

Comment: Probably that happens because of the flip library that you use. Maybe you could check it's code to see what exactly it does.

Comment: So what you're saying is that what I'm experiencing is not normal and that my code should theoretically work as is written here?

Comment: As you said in one of your comments when you do the flip the problem appears(and I don't know what that library does when you "flip the view"). One thing that I didn't understood, is the `detailsOn` variable supposed to change the status of all rows? If not shouldn't you have a status flag for each of the rows? Otherwise I'm thinking the rows will get reverted on their own based on the last toggle.

Comment: The library class used is called [FlipViewController](http://pastebin.com/cA3Hj8y1). Yes, you understood correctly. The boolean `detailsOn` is a global variable that dictates whether or not `txtvwComposition` displays a string. I want it so that once it's toggled, all views will display as chosen. Right now, as a layout gets displayed, it knows what the value of `detailsOn` is, but it won't update `txtvwComposition` as I flip to an adjacent page (probably because of how `getView` recycles objects) – though it will update if I flip 2 pages away from where I toggled `detailsOn`.